# Should I write a second reminder to the HR?

Tags: professionalism, human-resources, email

I'm attending a Dual Course of Study University, where a regular semester is compressed to 3 months and the other 3 months are occupied by working 40hr/month with a selected partner.

From time to time it happens that the students have to attend an exam during their working term. This is true in my case. Therefore, I already sent a formal request to get a day off for the exam (4hr + 1 hr commute each way), as this is specified in our examination regulations.

Unfortunately, the responsible manager has not yet replied. After 5 days I sent in a reminder, to which I also didn't receive a response.

Should I send a 3rd request (2nd reminder) or should I wait longer?

Comment: Emails can get lost, forgotten, or ignored. If you need a response now (Or very soon), it might be an idea to go talk to a person. You tend to get a response better if you have a verbal communication.

Answer (score 2):

As @Draken mentioned in the comments, the email could have been lost, forgotten or ignored (for example it could have accidentally made it's way into the person's spam / junk directory).

You could consider speaking to them in person, contacting them telephonically, or sending another email but CC-ing somebody else at the company who could also be responsive on the matter.

Something also worthwhile considering is having a physical print-out which requires signing if you need permission to have the day off.

Answer (score 1):

Responses from moose and draken highlight the appropriate route. As a manager receiving hundreds of emails weekly it is very possible for items to get lost in the shuffle. A telephone call should be the next appropriate step. (Assuming that you are following your organizations proper process for requesting time off)
I do think that this post highlights a major issue developing in the shifting norms from one generation of employees to the next. While email has its advantages, as pointed out by Vietnhi, it comes at the cost of direct interaction. Phone calls, and face to face meetings not only help to resolve issues quickly, but also provide an opportunity for you as an employee to develop a working relationship with your supervisors. Had you directly spoken with this supervisor at an earlier available opportunity, you could have saved yourself some of the hardship to date.

Answer (score 0):

Send a third email ASAP - you have to protect yourself and if the manager  complains, you can point to a stream of emails that you sent them. At some point, you should send him an email to your manager once a day with the email marked "high priority". cc: HR and whoever else you think is relevant. Like your team leaders and your co-workers.

Depending on how many days you've got left before Exam Day, you are going to have get in your manager's face and ask him point blank for a personal day off. "I have emailed you repeatedly but this can't wait any longer. I really need your okay to take this day off". Don't wait until the last minute before you ask - Ideally, you should ask the week before. If it is already the last minute, it's just too bad - ask away and ask immediately.

If worst comes to worst and you have zero success getting any response from your manager no matter what you try, call Reception on the morning of Exam Day and tell them that you are taking a day off to attend to personal business and that you have notified you manager repeatedly to that effect. Then do what you have to do. On the morning after, send your manager an email stating that you took care of your personal business yesterday and that you are back at work this morning. My personal touch: don't apologize for having taken the personal day off.